# User undefined | AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, service, scope

I'm trying to declare a variable & I want to to be added to global variable after doing a get function with a loop

So just to be clear, I'm making a page where users can view other people's profiles and I've got it to work.. I can scope on the page using the following:

viewProfileCtrl.js

```
var id = $stateParams.id;
var user; //------------------------- > UNDEFINED

    userApi.getUsers().then(function(res) {
        console.log(res.data);
        var count, i;
        for (i=0; i<=res.data.users.length; i++)
        {
            var users_id = res.data.users[i].user_id;
            console.log(users_id);
                if (users_id == id) {
                    $scope.user =  res.data.users[i];

                    //return this
                    return user = $scope.user; 
                    //^-------> return this to the global variable
                } 
        }
    });

    console.log(user); -------> undefined even after the loop.
```

**Edit: Added the above console.log for extra explanation.**

The `userApi.getUsers()` is a service function to retrieve all the users from Auth0.

**userService:**

```
getUsers : function () {
            return $http(
            {
                method: 'GET', 
                url: urlBase, 
                headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ 
                'TOKEN'},
            });
        }
```

**Recap** (if the above wasn't clear)**:**

I basicly want to fill the var user with the user's info that I retrieve when doing the loop.

I want to be able to use the data that I retrieve in another function
example:

```
$scope.profilePic = function(pic) {
        if(user.identities[0].provider === "facebook"){
            pic = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + $scope.user.identities[0].user_id + "/picture?width=9999";
        } else {
            pic = auth.profile.picture;
        }
        return pic;
    };
```

For the following I will get `cannot retrieve the identity of undefined`, seeing user stays undefined for some reason.

Comment: Your code will do that, set the variable `user` with the one matching. What does not work, what is your question?

Comment: It doesnt, var user stays undefined outside the loop. so for example: if I were to `console.log(user);` after the loop, it's undefined.

Comment: @floribon I updated my OP, might make it all a bit more clear.

Comment: `userApi.getUsers` is asynchronous, it takes time to query the server and only when it's done will the callback (the code with the loop) be executed. You cannot simply log `user` just below this async call, you need to do that inside the callback. I invite you to read more about asynchronous VS synchronous code in JavaScript.

Comment: I should of figure that out.. Thanks for the info